# Explaining something with Schwarz reflecting principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Im reading about biholomorphisms from the disk to the to the upper half plane and in my book, the author explains that the only automorphisms of the unit disc are of the form $ e^{i\theta}\left(\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}\right),|\alpha|<1 $, which I already know, but he also explains the intuition:

If we assume that $ f $, an automorphism of the disk is bilinear, and $f(\alpha)=0$ for fixed $\alpha $ with $0<|\alpha|<1 $, then since $ f $ is globally 1-1 it must map the unit circle onto itself and we can thus apply **Schwarz Reflection Principle** to conclude that $ f\left(\frac{1}{\overline{\alpha}}\right)=\infty $.

And another example is when the author explains that the biholomorphisms of the upper half plane onto the unit disk are of the form $ h\left(z\right)=c\left(\frac{z-a}{z-\overline{a}}\right) $

And once again, he explains the intuition and states that since the real axis is mapped into the unit circle, it follows by **Schwarz Reflection Principle** that $ h\left(\overline{\alpha}\right)=\infty $ (and that the intuition of how to get to the former expression).

I'd like to understand whats the relation to Schwarz reflection principle. As far as I know, if $\gamma(t) $ and $\lambda(t) $ are regular analytic paths such that $ f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\subset\lambda $

Then we have $ \left(f\left(z^{*}\right)\right)^{\#}=f\left(z\right) $

Where $*$ denotes reflection with respect to $\gamma $ and # means reflection with respect to $\lambda$.

Also regular paths are 1-1 which circle are not regular paths, so Im not sure how the reflection principle takes place here/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reflection point of $\alpha$ with respect to the unit circle is $1/\bar \alpha$, and the reflection point of $0$ is $\infty$. Therefore, if $T$ maps the unit circle onto itself and $T(\alpha) = 0$ then $T(1/\bar \alpha) = \infty$.

Comment: @MartinR This one I figured out with the formula you gave me yesterday, so I understand the the proof for that formula comes from Schwarz reflection principle. I'd appreciate an explanation of how exactly , so I can know how to find reflections of points with respect to other geometric shapes (for exapmle, to understand the second example I gave)

Comment: It works the same in the second example, only that the reflection point of $\alpha$ with respect to the real axis is $\bar \alpha$.